# Getting nulls when trying to post data using spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have made a crud ajax rest application using spring framework. The problem is:
When i am sending post from client to server, i am getting object filled with nulls, from client side i have status 200. Here is my code:

**Product class**

```
public class Product {//getters,setters and toString() generated with Eclipse
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     private String description;
     private String createdDate;
     private Integer placeStorage;
     private Boolean reserved;
```

**Rest controller**

```
@RestController
public class ProductRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceImpl productService;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/getRecord")
    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        System.out.println(product);
    }
    
}
```

**AJAX function**

```
function sendRecord(data){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/getRecord',
            contentType : "application/json",
            cache : false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData:false,
            data: data,
            dataType:'json',
            success : function(data) {
                update_table();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Data that i am posting**

[image: Data that i am posting]

**Data that i am getting**

[image: Data that i am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into @RequestBody annotation https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getRecord")
    public void addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        System.out.println(product);
    }
```

It will automatically map request body data into your Product object. If you got time also take a look into `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`, they are all for data getting and works in differents ways for different goals.

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell Spring where to get your product from. You miss an annotation.

```
@RestController
public class ProductRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceImpl productService;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/getRecord")
    public void addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        System.out.println(product);
    }
    
}
```

You should also think about rename /getRecord since you don't get anything but send something. :)

Comment: Plus 1 for the url changing tip.

Comment: Thank you all guys, i solved my problem with your help. I also change the /getRecord as you suggested me :)